# java Haversine formula (math) NullPointerException error problem

Tags: java, math

I am trying to create Haversine formula calculator.
for more info, got to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

I have error in output:

```
longitude and latitude of home : 
20.593683 78.962883
longitude and latitude of travel destination : 
56.130367 106.346771
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at haversine.execute(test28.java:14)
at test28.main(test28.java:32)
```

My code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class haversine {
        double long1;
        double lat1;
        double long2;
        double lat2;
        haversine (Double long1, Double lat1, Double long2, Double lat2) {
                this.long1 = long1;
                this.lat1 = lat1;
                this.long2 = long2;
                this.lat2 = lat2;
        }
        double execute() {
                return Math.pow(Math.sin((lat2 - lat1)/2) ,2) + Math.cos(long1) * Math.cos(long2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((long2 - long1)/2) ,2);
        }
        double disCalc (Double exe) {
                Double radius_of_earth = 6378.1;
                return 2 * radius_of_earth * Math.asin(Math.pow(exe, 2));
        }

}
class test28 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("longitude and latitude of home : ");
                double long1 = scan.nextDouble();
                double lat1 = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("longitude and latitude of travel destination : ");
                double long2 = scan.nextDouble();
                double lat2 = scan.nextDouble();
                haversine obj = new haversine(long1, lat1, long2, lat2);
                double exe = obj.execute();
                double distance = obj.disCalc(exe);
                System.out.println("The Distance is : " + distance);
                scan.close();


        }
}
```

Please tell me whats the error.

Comment: Have you checked the values for `long1`, `lat1`, `long2`, `lat2`?

Comment: means? If you are are taking about its existence. yes these vales exist.

Comment: no, I mean what's their value when you call `haversine`'s constructor.

Comment: when i create object : haversine obj = new haversine(long1, lat1, long2, lat2); In the first line of input. i take values of long1 and lat1 and in second line i take long2 and lat2. and these values are set when i create the object

Comment: I know that. I mean are you sure that, at runtime, they actually have those values? Because by my count line 14 is the body of `execute`, and the only reason to have a NPE there is if one or more of those values were not initialized. And it would be interesting to know why you're using `Double` and not `double`, but that's another story.

Comment: how to find out if it is initialised or not

Comment: Just print them. Or use a debugger.

Comment: actually. the problem was in capitalisation "D" in Double. now the output is comings thanks! btw what is the difference in Double and double? i am beginner

Comment: The first is a class, the other is a primitive data type. They have different semantics. If you're a beginner I suggest you don't think too much about it right now and just use `double`, `int` etc. When you'll get to learn generics you'll understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in capitalization "D" in Double. The first is a class, the other is a primitive data type. They have different semantics.